# Реализация демультиплексора (Ошибка)

Tags: vhdl

X - Значение.

W - Порт разрешения (инверсный по заданию).

Addres - адрес выхода.

Y - выходы.

Мой код:

```
library ieee;
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;
use ieee.numeric_std.all;

entity DEMUX is
    port (
        X: in std_logic;
        Address: in std_logic_vector(0 to 3);
        Y: out std_logic_vector(0 to 15);
        W: in std_logic
    );

end DEMUX;
architecture struct of DEMUX is
begin
    Y <= (to_integer(unsigned(Address)) => (not W) and X, others => '0');
end struct;
```

Так тоже ничего не меняет : `others => 0`
Собственно ошибка:

> Error (10318): VHDL aggregate error at DEMUX.vhd(16): choice must be
>   constant

Ещё не слишком освоился, подскажите пожалуйста что поменять.

Answer (score 0):

Это означает, что данная конструкция не может выполнить функцию демультиплексора, т.е., например, если вместо `to_integer(unsigned(Address))` Вы напишите константу, например:

```
Y <= (4 => (not W) and X, others => '0');
```

Конструкция будет корректно синтезирована, только все равно не в мультиплексор, а просто в элементы **НЕ** и **И**, выход которого пойдет на **Y**.
Для описания демультиплексора необходимо прописать все варианты как, например, это приведено здесь http://vhdlguru.blogspot.com/2010/03/simple-1-4-demultiplexer-using-case.html
либо, если пока не хотите использовать конструкцию `process`, описать через конструкцию `with...select`:

```
architecture rtl of my_example is
begin

with (Address) select
Y <= (0 => X, others => '0') when "0000",
"0000000000000010" when "0001",
......
"0000000000000000" when others;
end my_example;
```